# Add Array in nsmutableaary

Tags: ios, nsarray

i am developing instragramm type app when user tap like button i want add username in likes arry 
So I have a dictionary in a dictionary with arrays. I am trying to add to the arrays that are in the likes array.

```
    {
    caption = "Shakira Shakira...";
    comments =         (
    );
    "display_name" = Shakira;
    ext = "<null>";
    "image_id" = 53;
    likes =         (
    );
    "post_type" = i;
    "total_comments" = 0;
    "total_likes" = 0;
    "upload_dt" = 3wk;
    "user_id" = 7;
    "user_liked" = 0;
},
    {
    caption = "Addicted to Shakira???";
    comments =         (
                    {
            comment = "love your profile :)";
            "display_name" = Rihanna;
            "user_id" = 5;
        },
                    {
            comment = "You are my favorite celebrity on Follow Me.";
            "display_name" = Pitbull;
            "user_id" = 4;
        },
                    {
            comment = "Looking Good!";
            "display_name" = "Justin Bieber";
            "user_id" = 2;
        }
    );
    "display_name" = Shakira;
    ext = "<null>";
    "image_id" = 52;
    likes =         (
                    {
            "display_name" = "Justin Bieber";
            "user_id" = 2;
        },
                    {
            "display_name" = Rihanna;
            "user_id" = 5;
        },
                    {
            "display_name" = Pitbull;
            "user_id" = 4;
        }
    );
    "post_type" = i;
    "total_comments" = 3;
    "total_likes" = 3;
    "upload_dt" = 2mth;
    "user_id" = 7;
    "user_liked" = 0;
},
```

i want add display_name and user_id

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *mutearr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

here array is NSArray and mutarr is NSMutablearray

Answer (score 0):

You can use addObjectsFromArray: from NSMutableArray class

```
NSArray *animal = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Lion",@"Tiger",@"Dog",@"Cat",@"Sheep",@"Wolf", nil];
NSArray *color = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Red",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Black", nil];

NSMutableArray *all = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[all addObjectsFromArray:animal];
[all addObjectsFromArray:color];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var displayNames = [String]()

 var userIds = [Int]()

 let responseArray = (yourArray as? [NSDictionary]) ?? []

 for ar in responseArray{

     let display_name = ar.value(forKey: "display_name") as? String
     displayNames.append(display_name ?? "")

     let user_id = ar.value(forKey: "user_id") as? Int
     userIds.append(user_id ?? 0)
 }

 print(displayNames,userIds)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).